# Bin Function with Squared Brackets

Tags: bin

```py
def add_binary(a,b):
    return bin(a+b)[2:]
```

Why is "[2:]" used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert number into it's binary and remove first two characters 0b.

Example: 
Original number: 10 
Binary string: 0b1010

after that it will be 1010 only.